# Multi threading sum

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
class Locker{
    mutex &m_mtx;
    public:
    Locker(mutex& mtx) : m_mtx{mtx}{m_mtx.lock();}
    ~Locker(){m_mtx.unlock();}
};
mutex mtx;
int globalOutput = 0;
void sum(const vector<int>& vect, int start, int end)
{
    for(auto i = vect.begin() + start; i != vect.begin() + end; ++i)
        {
            Locker{mtx};
            globalOutput+= *i;
        }
}

int main()
{
    const vector<int> vct(500, 2);

    thread th1(&sum, vct, 0, 250);
    thread th2(&sum, vct, 250, 500);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    std::cout << globalOutput;
}
```

I used a custom `mutex` class to synchronize two threads that calculate the sum of 500 items having the value 2.
Do you know of another way to sync threads? Share knowledge, thank you!

Comment: You can just use [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of your custom `Locker` class.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Please elaborate on your problems and your question. Also please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why are you using a custom mutex class?

Comment: You can start these tasks by `std::async` then to get final result `task1.get() + task2.get()` and in this way you don't need to have any synchronization inside `sum` function.

Comment: I'm using a custom class because in a more complex architecture the `mutex` can remain locked @molbdnilo

Comment: Is it safe to use std::atomic ?

Comment: @IonutAlexandru What is the actual goal here? Synchronizing threads? Or calculating a sum in parallel?

Comment: If you want to calculate the sum in parallel, I would advice to have a local variable to sum the range of the thread and only update the globalOutput after the loop.

Comment: The goal is Synchronizing threads. Is just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `Locker{mtx};` in:

```
{
   Locker{mtx};
   globalOutput+= *i;
}
```

creates an object `Locker` which locks the mutex `mtx`, but this object is destroyed right away and the mutex is unlocked. Therefore, `globalOutput` is modified by the thread while not holding a lock on the mutex. You may want instead:

```
{
   Locker locker{mtx};
   globalOutput+= *i;
   // locker object destroyed here
}
```

That is, you want to keep the lock on the mutex while modifying `globalOutput`.

---

#### Use `std::lock_guard` or `std::scoped_lock`

You can just use [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of your custom `Locker` class:

```
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
   globalOutput+= *i;
}
```

Since C++17 you can simply use [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock), which renders `std::lock_guard` obsolete:

```
{
   // take advantage of C++17 template argument deduction for constructors
   std::scoped_lock lck(mtx);
   globalOutput+= *i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to calculate the sum in parallel, but you don't actually care how it happens, you can also use [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce). Note that this requires C++17.

Using that your complete example code becomes:

```
int main () {
  const vector<int> vct(500, 2);
  auto sum = std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, vct.begin(), vct.end());
  std::cout << sum;
}
```